# Similar endings of names of berries

Tags: словообразование

Why "черника", "брусника", "голубика", "костяника", "клубника" and "земляника" all finish on "-ика" or even "-ника"?

Comment: downvoted since it's a very strange thing to ask to be honest.

Comment: Because langualge is mostly logical and likes to give similar names to similar things?

Comment: From the Proto-Indo-European suffix -ik- (compare Veronica, America, swastika, Mathematica etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suffix -ик- is fairly common amongst Slavic languages. Wiktionary has a great explanation for its usage in Proto-Slavic and its descendants: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/-ica

Proto-Slavic is a reconstructed language, so keep that in mind.

The main working theory among linguists is that the names of berries satisfy the meaning 4: carrier of a property. As such черника is a berry that is black (черный) while земляника is a berry that grows close to the ground (земля). Голубика is blue (голубой), and I presume that костяника has a large stone inside (I have no idea—I've never eaten it :)).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happened - you've chosen a subset of berries to prove some hypothesis which actually doesn't hold true if you care to have a bigger set. True, `-ника` is very productive when it comes to berries, however here's (incomplete) list of other berries:

- облепиха
- черёмуха
- малина
- черноплодка
- вишня
- черешня
- чёрная и красная смородина
- клюква
- морошка
- рябина
- крыжовник

Those are, of course, berries in a non-scientific sense (as far as I remember "малина" strictly speaking is not a berry, just like as "земляника" by the way) - but people percept them as such.

Now imagine someone coming up with a question why name of the berries end with "-ка" or "-ха" (or, "-ня", whatever) in Russian.

Comment: But the question wasn't "why _all_ berries end like that"; rather: why so many do. There must be something typical and productive about -ика, and this can have a valid answer.

Comment: Also, арония, кизил...